# PHP form submission returns blank

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm a total novice so please bear with me :)…I've managed to create a form and used PHP to send the data to an email address. However, once I click submit; the screen goes blank instead of staying on the current page and displaying a message. I'm guessing i'm missing some sort of PHP code?

Also, i'd like to use the JQuery validator plugin on my form, how can I add it without basically screwing up the form?

MY HTML:

```
<div>
<form id="form_id" name="form_name" action="scripts/index.php" method="post">
                <div>
                    <label for="name">Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John Smith" required/>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="email">Email: </label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@mail.com" required/>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="message">Message: </label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
            <p id="feedback"><?php echo $feedback; ?></p>
</div>
```

MY PHP:

```
<?php

$to = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from The Rocket Factory';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$body = <<<EMAIL

Hi, my name is $name.

$message

From $name
My Address is $email


EMAIL;

$header = "From: $email";

if($_POST){
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
    $feedback = 'Thanks for your message';
}

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is the `$body` code? Why do you have <<< there?

Comment: If you want to stay on the page, your form action should forward back to your HTML at the very end.

Comment: is your php above your html on the same page (scripts/index.php) ?

Comment: You could just have your form post to itself.  Put an if(isset($_POST) in to process the form if it has been submit.

Comment: The PHP file is in index.php

Answer (score 1):

`PHP` script that you create will return an empty page, because that script just to send email. I think you need to combine `PHP` script and `HTML` script together with `PHP` script in top of script to get that you want and edit form action to empty like this sample:

```
<?php

$to = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from The Rocket Factory';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$body = <<<EMAIL

Hi, my name is $name.

$message

From $name
My Address is $email


EMAIL;

$header = "From: $email";

if($_POST){
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
    $feedback = 'Thanks for your message';
}

?>

<div>
<form id="form_id" name="form_name" action="" method="post">
                <div>
                    <label for="name">Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John Smith" required/>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="email">Email: </label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@mail.com" required/>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="message">Message: </label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
            <p id="feedback"><?php echo $feedback; ?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form will take the user to scripts/index.php. You are echoing the '$feedback' var on the page with the HTML form. Redirect from scripts/index.php using
        header("location: filelocation");
        exit();

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways : 
1. Have php and html code in one page.
2. Use ajax to submit your form.

```
 <div>
    <form id="form_id" name="form_name" action="scripts/index.php" method="post">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John Smith" required/>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@mail.com" required/>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="message">Message: </label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
 </div>

   <?php

     $to = 'example@gmail.com';
     $subject = 'Message from The Rocket Factory';

     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
      $message = $_POST['message'];

      $body = <<<EMAIL
         Hi, my name is $name.
           $message
         From $name
        My Address is $email
       EMAIL;

  $header = "From: $email";

if($_POST){
     mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
    $feedback = 'Thanks for your message';
    echo '<p id="feedback">'.$feedback.'</p>'; <-- Notice this..
 }
?>
```

You can also use ajax in jquery ($.ajax) or javascript.

Comment: I just copied and pasted all of the above code and it still didn't work?

Comment: shall I change the action to '?' or 'index.html' or change the index.html page into 'index.php'

Comment: your page should be index.php, if its html nothing is going to work.

Comment: Cheers for the help! It works fine now - I moved the php to the top of the contact form page itself and changed the action to '?'

Comment: Cool.  I am glad it worked.  You can also give the same page name if you want instead of "?".